# How do you test the consistency models and race conditions on Google App Engine / NDB?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

Setup: Python, NDB, the GAE datastore. I'm trying to make sure i understand some of the constraints around my data model and its tradeoffs for consistency and max-write-rate. Is there any way to test/benchmark this on staging or on my dev box, or should I just bite the bullet, push to prod on a shadow site of sorts, and write a bunch of scripts?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [PseudoRandomHRConsistencyPolicy](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/localunittesting#Python_Writing_High_Replication_Datastore_tests) to control consistency in your tests. However, there are no way to test max-write-rate, as I know.

```
import unittest
from google.appengine.ext import testbed, ndb
from google.appengine.datastore import datastore_stub_util


class Foo(ndb.Model):
  pass


class TestConsistency(unittest.TestCase):

  def setUp(self):
    self.testbed = testbed.Testbed()
    self.testbed.activate()

  def tearDown(self):
    self.testbed.deactivate()

  def test_consistency(self):
    self.policy = datastore_stub_util.PseudoRandomHRConsistencyPolicy(
      probability=1)
    self.testbed.init_datastore_v3_stub(consistency_policy=self.policy)
    foo = Foo()
    foo.put()
    self.assertEqual(Foo.query().count(), 1)

  def test_consistency_failed(self):
    self.policy = datastore_stub_util.PseudoRandomHRConsistencyPolicy(
      probability=0)
    self.testbed.init_datastore_v3_stub(consistency_policy=self.policy)

    foo = Foo()
    foo.put()
    self.assertEqual(Foo.query().count(), 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You really need to do testing in the real environment. At best the dev environment is an approximation of production. You certainly can't draw any conclusions at all about performance by just using the SDK.  In many cases the SDK is faster (startup times) and slower (queries on large datasets.  Eventual Consistency is emulated and not 100% the same as production.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure it can be tested.  The inconsistencies are inconsistent.  I think you just have to know that datastore operations have inconsistencies, and code around them.  You don't want to plan on observations from your tests being dependable in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I am answering this over a year since it was asked.
The only way to test these sorts of things is by deploying an app on GAE. What I sometimes do when I run across these challenges is to just "whip up" a quick application that is tailor made to just test the scenario under consideration. And then, as you put it, you just have to 'script' the doing of stuff using some combination of tasks, cron, and client side curl type operations.

The particular tradeoff in the original question is write throughput versus consistency. This is actually pretty straightforward once you get the hang of it. A strongly consistent query requires that the entities are in the same entity group. And, at the same time, there is the constraint that a given entity group may only have approximately 1 write per second. 
So, you have to look at your needs / usage pattern to figure out if you can use an entity group.